# How to stream data on flask by editing previous data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a flask program such as:

```
@app.route('/')
def response():
    return("""
<div style="float:left; margin:10px">
    <h3 id="streamingdata">Loading...</h3> 
</div>
""")

@app.route('/')
def streamed_response():
    def generate():
        while True:
            yield("""
            <script>
                document.getElementById("livescore").innerHTML = "Hi";
            </script>
            """.format(newdata))
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

No errors show up but my program doesn't work as intended. My program is supposed to change the `"Loading..."` to whatever `newdata` comes in. However, the application only shows `"Loading..."`. What can I do to get my desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself and I'm posting the answer in case other may need it in the future. Basically, my problem was that I was returning two response on the same page. I simply combined the two functions and it worked.